# Having nothing on stdout when executing awk script

Tags: shell-script, awk

I run a awk script. But, it is here. This is the command `awk -f awk_scr ERR.txt`.

```
BEGIN {
FS=" " 
target="missing" 
}
{
for (i=1; i <= NR; i++) {
  for(j=1; j <= NF; j++) {
    if ($j == target) {
      do { 
        printf $j > "final.txt" 
      } while (j == NF)
    }           
    if (j == NF) {
      printf "\n"
    }
  }
}
}
```

The `ERR.txt` content is here. This awk script is for trimming what that is matched by **"missing"** and then print to a file, **final.txt**.

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.0.0, required by react-file-reader-input@1.1.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: jquery@1.9.1 - 3, required by bootstrap@4.2.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: tar@2.2.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by hawk@3.1.3
npm ERR! missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by boom@2.10.1
npm ERR! missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by sntp@1.0.9
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: glob@7.1.2, required by rimraf@2.6.1
npm ERR! missing: fs.realpath@1.0.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inflight@1.0.6, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: path-is-absolute@1.0.1, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.7, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@0.4.2, required by brace-expansion@1.1.7
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.7
npm ERR! missing: block-stream@0.0.9, required by tar@2.2.1
npm ERR! missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by tar@2.2.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by tar@2.2.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by block-stream@0.0.9
npm ERR! missing: graceful-fs@4.1.11, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: tar@2.2.1, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
```

But, when I execute the command, there is only a blank stdout.

**================ADD MORE CONTENT================**

This is what I expect to be, albeit I just spend few minutes to do. Anyway, the awk script is worth to use in the future.

```
    missing: react@^15.0.0, required by react-file-reader-input@1.1.4
    missing: jquery@1.9.1 - 3, required by bootstrap@4.2.1
    missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
    missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
    missing: tar@2.2.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
    missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by hawk@3.1.3
    missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by boom@2.10.1
    missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by sntp@1.0.9
    missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
    missing: glob@7.1.2, required by rimraf@2.6.1
    missing: fs.realpath@1.0.0, required by glob@7.1.2
    missing: inflight@1.0.6, required by glob@7.1.2
    missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
    missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
    missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
    missing: path-is-absolute@1.0.1, required by glob@7.1.2
    missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
    missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
    missing: brace-expansion@1.1.7, required by minimatch@3.0.4
    missing: balanced-match@0.4.2, required by brace-expansion@1.1.7
    missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.7
    missing: block-stream@0.0.9, required by tar@2.2.1
    missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by tar@2.2.1
    missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by tar@2.2.1
    missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by block-stream@0.0.9
    missing: graceful-fs@4.1.11, required by fstream@1.0.11
    missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by fstream@1.0.11
    missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by fstream@1.0.11
    missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by fstream@1.0.11
    missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
    missing: once@1.4.0, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
    missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
    missing: tar@2.2.1, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
    missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
    missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
    missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
    missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
    missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "trimming". Note that the code block that you have in your `awk` script will be executed once for each line in the input.  Having a loop over `NR` is therefore not needed, unless you'd like to do the inner loop once for the first line, twice for the second line, thrice for the third, etc.

Comment: You do not redirect your `LF` (`\n`) to the file.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the expected output, otherwise we can just guess what you want to achieve as your awk script is not clear.

Comment: You probably see nothing because you get stuck in an infinite loop: the `do while` loop does not alter `j`, so if `j == NF`, you're stuck. Did you check the file size of the final.txt file?

Comment: What's in `final.txt` for the sample input?

Comment: I add more content for explaining the matter.

Comment: I will focus the matter on infinite loop and LF(\n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# awk_scr

BEGIN {
    # clear the output file if it already exists
    # you can do this using your shell instead
    ORS = ""
    print "" > "final.txt"
    ORS = "\n"
}

/missing/ {
    # delete all characters prior to the last occurrence of "missing:"
    # this assumes that there is only one sub-string "missing:" per line
    sub(/.*missing:/, "missing:", $0)

    # append the updated line to the output file
    print $0 >> "final.txt"
}
```

Then run `awk -f awk_scr ERR.txt && cat final.txt`.

Another solution is to use `sed`, which is shorter:

`sed 's/^.*missing:/missing:/' ERR.txt | tee final.txt`

However, it has the same downside as the awk solution: it assumes that there is only one occurrence of "missing:" per line. This is due to the fact that both `awk` and `sed` only match greedily.

To simulate lazy matching, you can do the following, instead (which is better):

`sed -E 's/(missing)(.*)|./\1\2/g' ERR.txt | tee final.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your script is a bit convoluted and shows a misunderstanding of what 'awk' is all about.  Awk programs consist out of a list of

```
pattern { actions }
```

statement. Every time a new record/line is read, awk will process that line by executing the pattern-action statement one by one. From what I see, it looks like you imagine that awk reads the full file in memory and you can then process it using a for loop over the number of records. This is not how it works.

The following awk will probably do what you request:

```
awk '/missing/' inputfile > "missing.txt"
```

Here, the patter is `/missing/` and the action is the default action `1` which is equal to `{print $0}`, or print the full record. The pattern `/missing/` states, select all lines which contain the substring "missing"

Comment: Or just `grep -F 'missing:' <inputfile >missing.txt`.

Comment: I suspect `awk '/missing/ {print $NF}' inputfile > "missing.txt"` is what is wanted.